# Reading Data from a Numbers file in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a possibility of reading data from an Excel or numbers file in COCOA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in Cocoa API for these tasks, no.